# How to find a certain closest nested <select> from inside another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure in a form:

```
<div class='full'>
  <div class='half'>
    <label>Book</label>

    <select class='collection_ID'>
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">Geen leuk boek / &euro; <span>14.50</span></option>
      <option value="2">Cool boek! / &euro; <span>24.50</span></option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class='half'>
    <label>Find a book</label>
    <input type='text' class='invoke_search'>
  </div>
</div>

<button class='clone'>Another Book</button>
```

And here is my question. I have an input field

```
<input type='text' class='invoke_search'>
```

If a user decides to type some text and then moves on (i.e blur event) he/she wants to search a book by title in the  pretty close to it.

My jQuery function is the following:

```
$('.invoke_search').live('blur', function()
{  
  var needle   = this.value;
  var haystack = $(this).parent().parent().find('select').children();

  search(needle, haystack);
});
```

It's on a .live() event listener (or however you call that), because the clone button will create a copy/clone of the  ..  so a user can add more books to the form, this also means that I cannot use a unique ID on the , since the user has to search in a single  for an option and not in every select.

Now to get to my question, the following part is kind of hardcoded:

```
var haystack = $(this).parent().parent().find('select').children();
```

So I am looking for a way to use something like:

```
$(this).closest('select');
```

As if my form structure looked like:

```
<div class='full'>
  <label>Book</label>

  <select class='collection_ID'>
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Geen leuk boek / &euro; <span>14.50</span></option>
    <option value="2">Cool boek! / &euro; <span>24.50</span></option>
  </select>

  <label>Find a book</label>
  <input type='text' class='invoke_search'>
</div>
```

This would make styling pretty hard, so is there a way to use .closest() or .find() in some  smart way instead of 'hardcoded' parent().parent().find()?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a very detailed question. That makes it easy for an expert to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's always a `<div class="full">` wrapper then perhaps this would work:

```
var $select = $(this).closest('.full').find('select');
```

You just need something that contains both your `<input>` and `<select>` that can easily be identified using a selector, then hand that selector to [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to find the starting point for [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find).

Comment: Thanks, will accept this (but need to wait 5 mins :o) I feel so dumb lol :D

Comment: @Tessmore: `dumb + learning = less_dumb`, and sometimes "tunnel vision" is mistaken for "dumb" and we all suffer from tunnel vision.